# Using CartoDB to change projection of maps - then exporting as SVG

Tags: carto, geojson

This seems like a fairly simple question, but I've looked everywhere for the answer and can't find it.

I've imported geoJSON UK constituency data into CartoDB and it looks great. I now want to export this as an SVG to open in Adobe Illustrator, however when I do this my map looks like it has the wrong projection on it. (i.e The map is warped and I want it to appear flat.)

What can I do to fix this? Is there something I can do in CartoDB to get it to export flat?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having the same problem, I've stumbled on mapstarter.com which seems to add D3 code (with mercator projection) automatically when I export to SVG. This is obviously aimed at designers and works brilliantly. I would still be interested in knowing if this is possible with CartoDB, but for now, problem solved!